# How to handle exit() in NSOperation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, nsoperation

I have a C source code for as application that I want to use in my iPhone App. I thought the best way of doing it was to call the main method of that C Application in an `NSOperation` subclass.

This works fine, except for cases where something in the C application goes wrong and an `exit()`/`abort()` is called, which takes my whole iPHone App down with it.

The C code is very lengthy and I dont want to go through it or disturb it in any way. I would like to know if I can bypass those `exit()`/`abort()` calls in the `NSOperation` so that it just quits the thread and not the whole application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to compile with -Dexit=my_exit -Dabort=my_abort options and implement my_exit and my_abort as the following?

```
void my_exit(int status)
{
    if (!/* check thread ID or so forth, and check during calling the NSOperation */) {
        exit(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, can you explain on how do i set this in XCode?

Comment: Set "Other C Flags" to "-Dexit=my_exit -Dabort=my_abort" in Build Settings.

Comment: @jAmi: @ Kazuki Sakamoto: Not saying you *can't* use `Other C Flags` but the preprocessing section has a setting called `preprocessing macros` which saves you the `-D` part.

Answer (score 0):

As you are compiling the C code yourself you can add your own `exit()` and `abort()` functions, the C code will then call those rather than those in the library. Define them to pass an appropriate status to your Obj-C code and close down the thread.

For real isolation of course you want to use `NSTask`...

Comment: As I mentioned that I cannot tweak the C code. NSTask is not supported by iOS SDK .

Comment: Is NSTask available to an iPhone app?

Comment: @JeremyP,jAmi - correct, `NSTask` is not available, but that is what you need for real isolation... The last line was just passing commentary which obviously confused :-(

Comment: @jAmi - the suggestion is to add two functions to your existing C code, not to change it. @Kazuki's answer is exactly the same idea, but uses #define's to rename the functions and then supply definitions for the renamed versions. If you do not wish to alter your existing C code these two answers, or other variations of the same idea, are really the only approach you have available on iOS - there is no easy way for you to intercept/spoof the calls, and even if you did so you'd be violating the iOS app store rules. So you *must* compile your code such that it does not call the library versions.

Comment: @CRD: Can you use fork() and exec() in iOS?

Comment: @JeremyP: Well I don't see any prohibition in the docs, but that is hardly definitive. I've never tried it. Would not doing so violate the App Store rules, as iOS is designed to provide limited controlled multi-processing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any practical way to carry on after an `abort()`, possibly the same for an `exit()`.  Both of these calls actually terminate the process which means that the original programmer probably hasn't bothered to clean up allocated resources and file descriptors etc.  So even if you terminate the thread instead of the process, your application will almost certainly leak like a sieve whenever your overridden exit()/abort() is called.

More seriously, if the program has called abort(), it has probably detected some unrecoverable problem with its run time or a programmer error.  For instance, a buffer overrun might have corrupted the heap.  It may therefore be impossible to recover from the situation.

I'm afraid you'll have to audit every occurrence of `exit()` and `abort()` to see if it is even safe to just terminate the thread.

Comment: Cleaning up, if needed, is certainly an issue. Closing open file descriptors shouldn't be too hard, but reclaiming the memory used up by malloc & friends would be a bit more challenging. I can see violations of App Store rules might happen if you go this route... However if you simply want to catch an `abort()` so you can cleanly terminate your main thread, or the C code doesn't allocate a lot of memory and you can live with the leak, then going this route is possible - but as you correctly say, you need to know what your C code is doing!

Comment: Forgot: there is of course no complete way to protect against the C code going wild and writing over memory - but that can happen in Obj-C as well.